# How to redirect the request from tomcat server to another tomcat server

Tags: java

Assume that there is 2 tomcat server running say tomcat 1(ip address:101.155.55.15) and tomcat 2(ip address:101.155.55.16) User will be accessing some resource in tomcat 1,Tomcat 1 should redirect the request to tomcat 2 and tomcat 2 should send back the response to tomcat 1 i dont no how can i approach this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You have following two choices :

1. Either purchase as many public address
2. Put one server front and delegate these request.

Applying second approach we put Apache httpd web server in front of all others ip of servers. so only one public IP is enough. Apache httpd webserver communicate to Tomcat sever through AJP (Apache JServ Protocol) protocol.

Reference Link : [Reference](http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/03/virtual-host-apache-httpd-server-tomcat.html)

Comment: Thanks for solution but its not worked here i have two tomcat servers running JVM  as said in problem i stored some dashboard reports data in tomcat 2 so User will login [link](http://101.155.55.15:8080/webapplcation_name/somereports) so the request will redirect to tomcat server 2, i am not using APACHE HTTP SERVER here please help.